# How do I use the TPS5403 DC-DC buck to get 3.3V output from a 5-15V input?

Tags: circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, buck, design, datasheet

I am trying to use the [TPS5403](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS5403) ([datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps5403.pdf?ts=1691605648846&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)) buck converter to power an ESP32 at 3.3V from an input of 5-15V, however, I can't find enough resources online to be sure in my design.

Below, I have attached a circuit diagram.

- `VBUS` is my 5-15V power source
- `GND` is ground
- `3v3` is my 3.3V output

[image: Circuit Diagram Rev 2]

Is this the correct way to wire the TPS5403?

How does one wire a buck converter using information purely from the datasheet?

Comment: No, C2 is blocking the DC input. Vbus should go straight to pin 2 and C2 connects pin 2 to ground as per the "typical application" diagram on the datasheet.

Comment: Does the updated version seem correct?

Comment: Is 100 nF enough input capacitance?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the correct way to wire the TPS5403?

Cin is likely too low, the datasheet specifies a minimum input capacitance of 10uF. Otherwise it looks good to me based off of the typical application circuit, I didn't dive into the rest of the datasheet though.

> How does one wire a buck converter using information purely from the
> datasheet?

Generally follow the typical application circuit and the PCB layout sections of the datasheet. Read the detailed descriptions of each pin and the calculations needed for accompanying passives. Breadboard first when possible, that is useful for double checking and adjusting your passive values.

Comment: I think in this case (> 1 MHz switching frequency) breadboarding is probably not possible or at least not a good idea.

Comment: This chip is only available in SOIC package so breadboarding isn't really an option

Comment: @user1850479 the ROSC resistor value would be setting a frequency of 0.75MHz I believe. Also I thought 10MHz was the threshold for breadboard frequencies?

Comment: @Finbarr true, but not an impossible obstacle - I always keep SOIC-8 and SOT-23 breakout boards on hand for exactly this reason.

Comment: @InBedded16 Switching frequency and bandwidth are different things. In this case since it's capable of MHz switching it's probably in the 100 MHz (or even more) bandwidth range. Just as a general rule you probably won't be able to breadboard a modern commercial switching converter since they're so fast and so sensitive to parasitics.